# How to remotely reboot halted Pi

Tags: boot, usb, power, remote

I'm thinking of building an array of Pis but I'd like an intelligent method of powering them, i.e., I would like power to each to be controllable via USB. I like the [USB GPIO Module suggestion](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7085/easiest-way-to-control-a-pis-power-supply-via-usb) given here, however, I would like to know if the reset pin is an okay method of starting the Pi assuming it was properly halted.

The other method I considered was using a USB-controllable power strip, but the reset pin method sounds much cheaper if it's okay.

Comment: It seems the answer to my question is [here](http://raspi.tv/2012/making-a-reset-switch-for-your-rev-2-raspberry-pi). It's apparently a yes. :)

Comment: So please add it as an answer (community?)

Comment: I will add a detailed answer once I actually build the setup and can confirm it works (the method I am referring to is [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11656/how-to-remotely-reboot-halted-pi/11660?noredirect=1#comment15704_11660)). It may be a while before that happens though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to know if the reset pin is an okay method of starting the Pi assuming it was properly halted.

There isn't actually a pin, but there are [two holes at P6 on the rev. 2 board](http://raspi.tv/2012/making-a-reset-switch-for-your-rev-2-raspberry-pi) (~1cm left of the HDMI jack) that if shorted together will reset the power.  You can attach a switch to this.

Comment: Indeed. I was thinking of using just the GPIO Module suggested in the other question, or even another Pi/Arduino. (That is, make a simple switch circuit using a transistor [like the one here](http://www.geekingabout.com/controlling-12v-dc-motor-using-raspberry-pi-gpio-port.html), and then using whatever to control it to boot the Pis).