# PI-3 corrupted file system - run fsck on boot (Raspbian Stretch)

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, fsck, corrupt

I'm using a RPi3 with Raspbian Stretch and I have problems with corrupt file system. I use the Raspberry in a system where a "clean shutdown" is not possible. So I want to run fsck on boot. I have added the following in the `/boot/cmdline.txt` (I'm surprised that the file is empty after new Raspbian installation, so only the following parameters are added)

```
fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes
```

But when I restart the following error appears:

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on  unknown block(0,0)
```

How can I solve this problem? Or is there another way to automatically repair the file system when booting?

I used the Raspberry Pi 2 for a long time. Here I never had a problem with a corrupt file system. Is that a specialty of the Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: "I use the Raspberry in a system where a "clean shutdown" is not possible." sounds like a bad idea

Comment: maybe useful: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1403/78211

Comment: Note that the default `fsck.repair=yes` and implicit `fsck.mode=auto` would do what you want; see `man systemd-fsck`; when "the filesystem checker deems necessary" includes when it has not been cleanly unmounted.  WRT problems with a corrupt filesystem, they don't necessarily happen, but they *may* happen anytime you don't shutdown cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

`Raspbian` is a derivate of `Debian` and this isn't designed to work without a clean shutdown by default. May work with journaling on the root partition with `ext4` file system but it is only designed for disaster recovery one time. The boot partition has a simple `vfat` file system and do not have disaster recovery so it may be easy corrupted. Using it for years is your risk. We cannot help you to harden `Raspbian` for unclean shutdown. It isn't for this.

In a Raspbian image, e.g. [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-03-13](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) the `cmdline.txt` has this contents:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=a8fe70f4-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh
```

Don't know why yours is empty. Maybe it is corrupted by unclean shutdown?

Comment: Beware that `PARTUUID` may or may not work, but this is likely the problem (there is no root partition specified).  Although: Just noticed I have a Pi 3 with no `cmdline.txt` that boots fine :\ If the above doesn't work, `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` should.

Comment: @goldilocks I agree with you on [problems using `PARTUUID`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78308/79866). The `cmdline.txt` in my answer isn't a direct suggestion. It only shall show what's in the official image and that it isn't empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I can't tell you why my file is empty. I looked in the backup image I created after installation. Here the file is also empty. I changed the contents of the file as described above by Ingo and goldilocks. Now everything works! Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Is my answer acceptable?