# Raspberry pi 2b not booting after SD card was ejected while working

Tags: pi-2, boot, sd-card

So, like the title says: My Raspberry pi 2b is not booting after the card was ejected while working.
I was watching some Kodi media, then it froze, I realized that the SD Card was ejected (there is a problem in the slot).
After that even though I have formatted the SD card and copied NOOBS, the pi is not booting. It just stays with green and red lights on and not flashing.

I would love to hard reset it somehow if that could be of any use but can't find how.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || Alright, so, what do you want? The problem isn't clear enough (for me!). Add more details if it's possible.

Comment: hi thanks for the welcome. I make a question in the end of the paragraph: how to hard reset the raspberry pi. ( "Would love to hard reset it somehow if that could be of any use but can't find how. Any ideas?")

Comment: why don't you ask directly `how do you hard reset a Pi-2?` instead of `any ideas?`

Comment: May be solved by [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-do-i-hard-reset-a-raspberry-pi).

Comment: Have you tried different media? Perhaps the SD was corrupted/damaged?

Answer (score 2):

There is **NOTHING** to reset if you do a fresh installation.

Do **NOT** use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) install [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

If you install using Etcher (as recommended) this will verify the image after copying.

It is quite likely (if you have been using the same SD Card since the Pi2) that the SD Card is worn out - I suggest a new SD Card.

See [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) if you want to diagnose any problems.

Comment: Why would it be worn out? You can make fs read-only.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Had you mounted the FS ro, the SD card could not possibly wear out. I personally, don't do it, but I do disable `systemd-journald` and many other services that write to the SD card. Also, I link some directories to `/tmp`.